# При попытке указать `MediaElement`у `Source` где `Uri` будет начинаться с `https://`, получаем исключение?

Tags: c#, wpf

При попытке указать `MediaElement`'у `Source` где `Uri` будет начинаться с `https://`, получаем исключение:

> Ссылка на объект блаблаба...

При этом, если убрать `https://` и заменить его на `http://` любым способом, то он сам делает редирект на `https://` и спокойно читает медиа. В чем проблема, и можно ли это исправить?

Возникла такая необходимость в связи с тем, что веб сайт на который делаю запрос медиа, не поддерживает авторедирект, и отдает 404 страницу при запросе, который не является последовательным.

Comment: Это старый баг MediaElement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081956/how-to-make-a-wpf-mediaelement-play-when-its-source-is-a-https-uri

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702505/playing-media-from-https-site-in-media-element-throwing-null-reference-exception/41779361

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если отключить в студии режим "Только мой код" в настройках отладчика, можно получить стек, вызывающий данное исключение:

```
 PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayerState.OpenMedia(System.Uri source) + 0x10d bytes  
 PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayerState.SetSource(System.Uri source) + 0x27 bytes   
 PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayerState.Open(System.Uri source) + 0x27 bytes    
 PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.AVElementHelper.HandleStateChange() + 0x240 bytes    
 PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.AVElementHelper.MemberOnInvalidateSource(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) + 0x5b bytes   
 PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.AVElementHelper.OnSourceChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) + 0x67 bytes 
 WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) + 0x83 bytes         PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) + 0x9f bytes  
 WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) + 0x64 bytes  
 WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType) + 0x853 bytes  
 WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType, bool isInternal) + 0x3f7 bytes 
 WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value) + 0x52 bytes  
 WpfApplication1.exe!WpfApplication1.MainWindow.Button_Click_1(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) Line 31 + 0x42 bytes
```

Далее, глядя в код метода [OpenMedia](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/MediaPlayerState.cs,0e552532a1915f24), видим, что в случае, когда передаваемый URI имеет схему https, .NET пытается получить URI публикации для текущего приложения и далее, если этот URI не https, проделать некие телодвижения с целью проверки "безопасно ли сделать это в данном контексте". Но проблема в том, что URI публикации определен только в двух случаях: для браузерного WPF и для приложений ClickOnce. В остальных случаях этот URI будет иметь значение null, и, так как это не проверяется, имеем NRE.

Иными словами, как правильно заметил в комментариях demonplus, это обыкновенный баг в WPF. Как его обойти? Ну, самое простое, это перейти с MediaElement на что-то другое, например на [ActiveX-элемент Windows Media Player](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-an-activex-control-in-wpf), который обладает тем же функционалом, но избавлен от этой проблемы. Не то, чтобы MediaElement из WPF обладал какими-то особыми преимуществами. Однако, если вам действительно нужен MediaElement, можете воспользоваться следующим грязным хаком для принудительной установки URI публикации:

```
Assembly assPresentationCore = typeof(UIElement).Assembly; //PresentationCore.dll
Assembly assWindowsBase = typeof(System.Windows.Vector).Assembly; //WindowsBase.dll

//найдем информацию о типах
Type typeContainer = assPresentationCore.GetType("MS.Internal.AppModel.SiteOfOriginContainer");
Type typeDS = assWindowsBase.GetType("MS.Internal.SecurityCriticalDataForSet`1").MakeGenericType(typeof(Uri));
Type typeNullable = typeof(Nullable<int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType(typeDS);

//найдем информацию о необходимом закрытом поле
FieldInfo field = typeContainer.GetField("_siteOfOriginForClickOnceApp",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static 
    );

//создадим объект Nullable<MS.Internal.SecurityCriticalDataForSet<Uri>>
object objDS = Activator.CreateInstance(typeDS,
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null,
    new object[] { new Uri("http://localhost/") },
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    );
object objNullable = Activator.CreateInstance(typeNullable, objDS);

//установим значение поля
field.SetValue(null, objNullable);
```

**Обновление:** Данная ошибка была исправлена в WPF для .NET Core 3.1. Метод [OpenMedia](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/release/3.1/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationCore/System/Windows/Media/MediaPlayerState.cs#L840) больше не обращается к SecurityHelper.ExtractUriForClickOnceDeployedApp, и MediaElement теперь работает с https://

Comment: Думаю сойдет такой вариант =)